# Closest Value instead of Max Value in Knapsack problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization, knapsack-problems

I have a problem like the knapsack problem, except instead of finding the max value, I'm trying to find the closest value to a given value.

Anyone know where to start, have a name for this problem, or can point me to an example?

Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/49508/use-dynamic-programming-to-find-a-subset-of-numbers-whose-sum-is-closest-to-give) might be useful to you.

Comment: @phan801 Your link is a simplified version. Here we have (I assume) various items with different weights, and your total weight must still fit into the knapsack. Interesting problem. Obviously NP-complete, we can solve ordinary knapsack by trying to get as close as possible to the total value of all items.